# How to draw different points with canvas in Android

Tags: java, android, canvas

I'm developing an Android application, I have to implement a function that allow me to draw different point in an activity.

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public Paint paint;
    public List<Point> coords;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new DrawingView(this));

        paint = new Paint();
        coords = new ArrayList();

        ImageView iv = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.car);
        iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        iv.setLayoutParams(parms);
    }

    class DrawingView extends SurfaceView {

        private final SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
        private final Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

        public DrawingView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            surfaceHolder = getHolder();
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
              addpoint(event.getX(), event.getY());
            }
            return false;
        }

        public void addpoint(float x, float y){

            Point point = new Point();
            point.x = Math.round(x);
            point.y = Math.round(y);
            coords.add(point);

            for(int i = 0; i< coords.size(); i++) {
                Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
                canvas.drawCircle(coords.get(i).x, coords.get(i).y, 20, paint);
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everytime that I touch the screen I get and save the coordinates in a list, then I try to draw the list of point, but only one point remain on the screen, I don't understand why.

So how I can draw different point on the screen (and save it) ?

Another question: how I can show a background image ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official Javadocs:

> drawColor(int color) Fill the entire canvas' bitmap (restricted to the
>   current clip) with the specified color, using srcover porterduff mode.

So every time you draw a circle, first you clear the whole canvas with white color. So after a draw, the circle drawed before is cleared.

So one option is to save the current state of the background, and always draw it on top of the white, or try not using `drawColor`

Comment: Ok, another problem: when i draw a point if i rotate my phone the orientation change and the point disappears, how i can keep the point ?

Comment: Well did my answer solved your problem? Could you accept it? Then create an other question for an other problem please, and I'll try to answer it.

Comment: I solved this problem in one part, deleting the row relative the drawcolor, now more points appears, but not all..

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i< coords.size(); i++) {
      Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
      canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
      canvas.drawCircle(coords.get(i).x, coords.get(i).y, 20, paint);
      surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
}
```

should be

```
Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
for(int i = 0; i< coords.size(); i++) {
          canvas.drawCircle(coords.get(i).x, coords.get(i).y, 20, paint);
}
surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
```

`canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);` Everytime ereases all the canvas and `surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);` shows only the last added Circle